# How to point a domain to another e-mail domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record, dns-record

I've got a domain in the format `jason-bourne.com` which I use for my e-mail address with a paid e-mail provider. Now, I'm considering to use a second domain in the format `jasonbourne.com` as an "alias" for `jason-bourne.com`.

The reason is that I want to prevent confusion over whether the hyphen in the domain is correct or not (the "correct" domain is `jason-bourne.com`, i.e. with the hyphen).

Basically, what I want to achieve is that when someone incorrectly sends an e-mail to `mail@jasonbourne.com`, it will still be correctly sent to `mail@jason-bourne.com`. Though, I don't want to just connect a second domain to my e-mail account. Instead, I want to configure some DNS record that "redirects" any e-mails before they're even received by the mail server.

I prefer this solution, because adding a second domain to my e-mail account would require me to pay double the current subscription price, when I don't even want to ***send*** e-mails from that second domain, for example.

I've heard of `CNAME`s – can they be used for that?

Thank you!

Comment: You have to talk with your e-mailprovider. There's many ways to solve this, but ultimately the method **has** to be supported by your provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to configure some DNS record that "redirects" any e-mails before they're even received by the mail server.

There is no such record.

---

To clarify: the DNS record governing where senders should deliver e-mail is the [`MX` record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record). That MX DNS record routes e-mail to servers (not mailboxes)  and provides no other capabilities and certainly no address rewriting functionality.

The sender will (attempt to) deliver a message to a mail server listed in the MX records for that domain and then the configuration on the receiving the mail server(s) determines if the message will be accepted, rejected and or delivered to particular mailbox.

The receiving mail server is typically where you would configure that mail for both the example.com and example.org should be accepted and either that those two domains are equivalent and/or mail for jason@example.com should be delivered to the same mailbox as mail addressed to jason@example.org

It depends on the mail provider if and when they do: how they support that. A term you sometimes find is an *"alias domain"*.

Comment: Thank you! It seems Zoho and ForwardEmail are great alternatives that I'll use instead.